# How come TextMate's copy and paste never pastes the way you want it to?

Tags: macos, textmate

It's 99% of the time indented to the wrong place.

I was curious what I'm missing on how to make it so that I can copy a piece of text, and paste it in the same context of its indentation that was copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable re-indentation of pasted text in TextMate's preferences.

Comment: so much better!